How to make custom field in product form searchable in order lines
I created a custom field in product form. This field named as x_studio_part_number.
Now, i want this custom field searchable when searching for product in order line of purchase and sales model or other models.


I already tried modifying the views in product.template.search and product.product.search using odoo studio.

But, i have to use the "search more.." to prompt the advance search. I want to search directly in order line.


PS. We are using odoo online and studio. So, please give a suggestion/help the fits only we currently have. Or using Settings/Technical.

Unfortunately, there is no way to modify the functionality of the Many2one field input from Studio. What you have done is the only possible solution directly from Studio with regards to searching a related record's fields for a Many2one field.
FYI: When you click into the text input and start typing, a JavaScript Many2XAutocomplete widget/component performs a query on the database, searching the related model (product.product in your case, I believe) for names that contain the input string.
// In addons/web/static/src/views/fields/relational_utils.js:Many2xAutocomplete
search(name) {
    return this.orm.call(this.props.resModel, "name_search", [], {
        name: name,
        operator: "ilike",
        args: this.props.getDomain(),
        limit: this.props.searchLimit + 1,
        context: this.props.context,
    });
}

If you were implement a custom addon/module to enable the kind of search you want, you would probably have to modify this function by creating another class to extend from Odoo's Many2XAutocomplete component. Then you would have to create a custom Many2OneField field widget to utilize this component and have the Many2one field utilize this widget. Again, this would all involve JavaScript and backend code.
